# How to get the first three posts of a specific section in Hugo v0.59?

Tags: hugo, go-templates

In Hugo v0.52 I had the following template code that worked to get the posts of the "blog" section on my home page (simplified example):

```
{{ range where .Pages "Section" "blog"}}
    {{ .Title }}
{{ end }}
```

However, I upgraded to v0.59 and now the functionality is broken. It now only loads my base "blog" page, not the articles. I've looked through the docs and can't find anything to indicate it's changed.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out right after posting. In v0.59, it needs to be

```
{{ range where .Site.Pages "Section" "blog"}}
    {{ .Title }}
{{ end }}
```